# Can one change his Facebook profile into a Page? What happens to his friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-profile

One of my friends on Facebook, is a good-looking guy who started singing and sharing his music with public on his Facebook profile. Now he has about 5000 friends on Facebook and is quiet famous for part of people.

He's just created a Facebook page and has received around 100 likes. Now he thinks about using the potential of his 5000 friends to promote his page on Facebook. Can he change his profile into a page or transfer his friends to there? If yes, so what happens to his current friends? Should he invite them or ask them for permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, he can. His friends will become subscribers to the new page.

> When you convert your personal account to a Facebook Page, we'll transfer your current profile picture and add all your friends and subscribers as people who like your Page. Your account's username will become the [username for your Page](http://www.facebook.com/help/pages/usernames), and the name associated with your personal account will become your Page's name. If you want your Page to have a different name, consider [creating a new one](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php).
>
> No other content will be carried over to your new Page, so be sure to save any important content before beginning the conversion:
>
> 1. Download your timeline information. You can [download a file](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=18830) that contains all of your sent and received messages and all of the photos and videos you’ve uploaded to Facebook.
> 2. Appoint a [new group admin](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=148640791872225) to any groups you manage. You'll be unable to manage groups once the conversion begins.
>
> When you're ready, [start converting](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?migrate) your personal account to a Facebook Page.

[Source](http://www.facebook.com/help/175644189234902/).